# How can I center an ImageView and TextView together?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make a heading with an ImageView and TextView that are centered together, like the following diagram.

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|    ----------- ----------    |
|    -ImageView- -TextView-    |
|    ----------- ----------    |
|                              |
|       -Other Content-        |
|                              |
```

The ImageView must be scaled to the height of the TextView and together they must be centered as if they were one widget. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EDIT: you can use TableLayout for it, put the textview and Imagview in 2 columns of tablerow, then your imageview is adjust acccording to your textview's columns height.

use your textview's height as wrap_content and imageview's height fill_parent
```

Comment: As was noted below: using a LinearLayout how can I accomplish the scaling I need for the ImageView?

Comment: Padding or margins are not a solution because the width of the ImageView is variable.

Comment: pading and margins are for your views center alingment. when you wrapper your imageview and textview with one linearlayout with properties layout_height="wrap_content" then its always adjust with the textview's and linear layout's height.

Comment: I set all of the layout height and width properties to wrap_content but ImageView remains too tall.

Comment: well thats your problem you dont wnat the image to wrap_content.  You want it to scale and be submissive to whatever the textview's height is.   set imageview to match_parent and textview to wrap_content, and the containing layout to wrap_content.

Comment: The TextView's Height is not fixed, the text is dynamic based on the data.

Comment: With the ImageView set with match_parent and TextView and container set to wrap_content the ImageView fills the entire layout as if it were scaled up.

Comment: match_parent is only support to android's new version.

Comment: I did set my API Level to 8 so that I could support match_parent but its not working.

Comment: for the experiment purpose, if we use tablelayout with two columns one for textview and other for imageview then see what happens. I think imageview's height is adjust with respecte to textview's column.

Comment: TableLayout with ImageView set with fill_parent and TextView and container set with wrap_content works so I can return to API Level 7 without issue. Thank you! Please update your answer so I can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If they must look as a single widget, then wrap them with a horizontal LinearLayout, and actually do treat it like a single widget. Centering this new 'widget' will do what you want.

Comment: Using a LinearLayout how can I accomplish the scaling I need for the ImageView?

Comment: The image must be scaled to the height of the textview, so set the layout_height of the linear layout to wrap_content, and the one for the image to fill/match_parent. This should work as long as the textview is taller than the image.

Comment: The image is actually bigger than the text. I can't guarantee that the image will be taller or shorter.

Comment: so set the textview's layout_height to wrap_content and the imageview's to match_parent?

Comment: No way to know without actually trying, but the answer is down that road somewhere... Let the OP experiment with it.

Comment: I did experiment and it did not work, please see the accepted answer's comments for how it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout`. Align `ImageView`'s top and bottom with `TextView`'s top and bottom. Set Top margins for textview. Set center horizontally to true in parent layout.

Comment: Using RelativeLayout how to I get the TextView to be positioned to the right of the ImageView without a circular dependency with the ImageView?

Comment: Place imageview to the left of textview.